# reporting logs in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to the protractor. I am trying to report logs to my specs using if and else condition.
My spec is true and thus my if condition is also true.It should not enter in the else statement but it does.

```
it("Check if the Url works ",function() //spec1
    {
        console.log("check if the URL works")
        browser.get(browser.params.url);
        if(expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("report"))
        {
            console.log("Result: URL works-PASS");//should enter here
        }
            else
            {
                console.log("Result: URL doesnt works-FAIL");
            }
    });
```

Can you please advice me how can I write better logs in protractor and what can I do to correct this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fail` to report a failure:

```
browser.get(browser.params.url);
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(value){
  if(/report/.test(value) === false) {
    fail("Result: URL doesnt works-FAIL");
  }
})
```

Comment: How to add Pass statement with above same code. e.g. i want add pass statement pass("Result: URL doesnt works-Pass"); , But i did not found pass function